# Pandas GroupBy Function with expanded columns

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pivot-table

I have the following table:

|  | Brand | Product |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Nike | Shoes |
| 1 | Nike | Socks |
| 2 | Adidas | Shoes |
| 3 | Adidas | Shoes |
| 4 | Adidas | Socks |
| 5 | Flight | Shorts |

I want to use the Pandas GroupBy function to produce the following table (totals for rows and columns) to find the number of occurrences that a specific Brand-Product Pair have.

|  | Shoes | Socks | Shorts | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Nike | 1 | 1 | 0 | 2 |
| Adidas | 2 | 1 | 0 | 3 |
| Flight | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| Total | 3 | 2 | 1 | 6 |

And then want to convert the cells in terms of Percentages:

- The cell % comes from diving the cell value by the column total (e.g., {Shoes, Adidas} = 2/3 = 67% or {Total, Adidas} = 3/6 = 50%)

|  | Shoes | Socks | Shorts | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Nike | 50% | 50% | 0% | 33% |
| Adidas | 67% | 50% | 0% | 50% |
| Flight | 0% | 0% | 100% | 17% |
| Total | 100% | 100% | 100% | 100% |

Also, on a final note, is there a way to multiply all cell numbers by an adjustment factor (e.g., 0.75)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `pd.crosstab`:

```py
out = pd.crosstab(df["Brand"], df["Product"])
out["Total"] = out.sum(axis=1)
out.index.name, out.columns.name = None, None
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
        Shoes  Shorts  Socks  Total
Adidas      2       0      1      3
Flight      0       1      0      1
Nike        1       0      1      2
```

---

Edit: To get percentages, you can do afterwards:

```py
out.iloc[:, :-1] = (
    out.iloc[:, :-1]
    .div(out["Total"], axis=0)
    .mul(100)
    .round(0)
    .astype(int)
    .astype(str)
    + "%"
)

out["Total"] = (
    out["Total"]
    .div(out["Total"].sum())
    .mul(100)
    .round(0)
    .astype(int)
    .astype(str)
    + "%"
)
```

Prints:

```
       Shoes Shorts Socks Total
Adidas   67%     0%   33%   50%
Flight    0%   100%    0%   17%
Nike     50%     0%   50%   33%
```